# How to set enable and disable for switch button

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Here is when i click the button this code is working

```
openRightMenu() {

     this.props.toogleCollapse();
    }

   <Button  onClick={this.props.toogleCollapse}> /></Button>
```

I need How to set the above Button onclick function to the switch .that mean when i enable  switch this function need to work  onClick={this.props.toogleCollapse}.How to do? My switch code :

```
<Switch size="small" checked={disabled} onChange={this.handleDisabledChange} />
```

handleDisabledChange function code:

```
handleDisabledChange = (disabled) => {
    this.setState({
         disabled 
        });
    }
```

[image: Switch]

Comment: Where do your `Button` and `Switch` components come from? Could include your entire component?

Comment: Your question doesn't make any sense. Also, is this React Native by chance?

Comment: @Tholle ant design sir

Comment: @Li357 react js

Comment: Your question still doesn't make sense. Could you clearly describe what you want to do, and what you have now (and what's wrong with it)?

Comment: @Li357 sir when i click button that onclick function working .i need to how to do when enable the switch then  onclike function must work

Comment: @Gnanaseelan So you want the onClick handler only to work when the switch is on? You can just use a state value to check whether the switch is on. Then in your onClick check if the switch is on, then execute

Comment: Have you tried `disabled={disabled}` as a prop on your Switch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Button's `onClick` is a `React.EventHandler` - its first arg. is the `Event` associated with the click. `disabled` in `toogleCollapse` [sic], will be set to the event.

*I think* what you want is

```
<Button  onClick={() => this.props.toogleCollapse(!disabled)}> /></Button>
```

... though there's a lot of code missing that would reveal some context so I could be totally off.